# Subtitles in <track> tag in <video> tag dont work

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, video

I have a simple question . I try play video(from computer) with subtitles file in browser . I am point src video file and it play without problem , but subtitles file in track tag dont work .

I have those console output :

Firefox: Security Error: Content at file:///home/aaa/video.html may not load data from file:///home/aaa/Welcome%20to%20the%20Course.vtt.

Chrome: Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///home/aaa/Welcome%20to%20the%20Course.vtt from frame with URL file:///home/aaa/video.html. 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Its very simple . I want only watch video with sbtls in browser for myself and decide do it in this way . Here  is a code without doctype .
...
`<body>
    <h1>Video</h1>
    <video src="/home/aaa/1. Welcome to the Course!.mp4">
        <track default kind="captions" src="/home/aaa/Welcome to the Course.vtt" srclang="en" label="English">
    </video>
</body>`

Comment: Can you add it in the post please, so it's easier to read for us

Comment: I also warmly suggest you read this since you are a new contributor:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask